# call java function in Qt

Tags: java, c++, qt

We have an application that make people to call. I want to turn on screen when user get a call, and turn off when user close it. I've tried this twice.first time, I adding flag by default. It was working. but in second situation , I didn't add anymore.

In java file , I've defined turnFlags to turn flags on/off. 

**CustomMainActivity.java:**

```
public void turnFlags(boolean onOff)
{
    if(onOff)
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);   
    else
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);    
}
```

In C++ file,  I decided to use turnFlags on different situation. I want to turn it on when callInvited, and turn it off when callClosed.

```
    void VoipTask::callInvite()
    {
    #ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
        QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<void>("turnFlags", "(Z)V", true);
    #endif
        CGlobalZone::m_callType = IncomingCall;

    #ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID

        m_answerDate = m_callDate = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        m_callState = MissedCall;
        m_transactionId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getTransactionId");
        m_callId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getCallId");
        m_dialogId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getDialogId");
    #else
        CGlobalZone::m_dialNumber = m_callNumber;
    #endif

        QApplication::postEvent(CGlobalZone::m_callsManager, new QEvent(QEvent::Type(CGlobalZone::HANDLE_CALL_EVENT)));

        startAudioDevices();

    #if !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) && !defined(Q_OS_IOS)
        if (CGlobalZone::m_ringtone.isEmpty())
            ring();
        else
            playRingtone();
    #endif
    }
void VoipTask::callClosed()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<void>("turnFlags", "(Z)V", false);
#endif
    stopConversation();
    stopAudioDevices();
    stopVoip();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID` twice. change it to:

```
   void VoipTask::callInvite()
    {

        CGlobalZone::m_callType = IncomingCall;

    #ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID

        m_answerDate = m_callDate = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        m_callState = MissedCall;
        QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<void>("turnFlags", "(Z)V", true);
        m_transactionId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getTransactionId");
        m_callId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getCallId");
        m_dialogId = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("getDialogId");
    #else
        CGlobalZone::m_dialNumber = m_callNumber;
    #endif

        QApplication::postEvent(CGlobalZone::m_callsManager, new QEvent(QEvent::Type(CGlobalZone::HANDLE_CALL_EVENT)));

        startAudioDevices();

    #if !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) && !defined(Q_OS_IOS)
        if (CGlobalZone::m_ringtone.isEmpty())
            ring();
        else
            playRingtone();
    #endif
    }
```